# How do I upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

These seem to get marked as duplicate... but there is an easily available piece of information that I had to do quite a bit of perusing to find that I think most users asking would like to see:

Per the [Fridge](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/04/17/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-released/) 
"Users of 12.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 14.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for July 24th."

I'm only posting this in case some other frustrated user is looking for this information, and like me, is not finding it in the other answers the "duplicates" are being referred to.

Comment: The information on how to upgrade is posed all over the internet. A simple google search yields several wiki pages - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade as well as the release notes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes and the Fridge http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/04/17/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-released/ and even http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-ubuntu-13-10-or-12-04/. In addition this has been answered here and thus this is a duplicate.

Comment: If problems arise, first check the release notes and known bugs. If you can not find a solution , ask for support here, IRC, forums, launchpad - http://www.ubuntu.com/support You will have to ask a more specific question. If you ask "how do I upgrade?" without any further details , yes your question is likely to be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I understood that the information was out there, but based on the search "how to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 I was unable to find the information provided on the Fridge without doing some digging.  All I found was the "upgrade to this then that then the other" business.  Hence, like I said, I was posting this in hopes someone else Googling about would run into it and have an easier time getting the info they were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to reach 14.04 LTS. I used 12.04 LTS upto 12.04.4 LTS. Then I upgraded it to 13.10. Yesterday, I upgraded from there to 14.04 LTS, through 'SOFTWARE UPDATER'. Open this from DASH. It would automatically search for all updates for your computer. Just follow it. I can assure you, you would never look back. 14.04 LTS is a gem of OS!

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 just do this command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Hope this helps. Alternatively you could wait for Ubuntu 14.04.1 (the first point release), when you will automatically get a prompt to update without executing a terminal command.